# Is $\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I was reading a textbook and for the exercise part I faced this question that asked to figure if this integration is converge or divergent.

I tried  to solve it with the limit comparison test and I couldn't find the proper function to compare with.

Can you tell me what do you think about this wanted function and how do you come up with that ?

I was wondering is it even a proper procedure to use limit comparison test?

$$\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}} dx$$

Comment: This may or may not be of use but
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\:dx =  \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Consider integrals over $[0,1]$ and $[1,\infty)$.

Try the limit comparison test with  $e^{-x}$ as $ x \to \infty$ and $1/\sqrt{x}$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Of course the simple comparison test works as well, e.g. $e^{-x}/\sqrt{x} < e^{-x}$ for $x>1$.