# $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was reading a textbook and for the exercise part I faced this question thst asked to figure if this integration is converge or divergent .
 I tried  to solve it with the limit comparison test and I couldn't find the proper function to compare with .
and i was wandering how should i think about it to improve my ability.

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1} dx $$

I will be very greatfull.

Comment: See also: [Is $\int_{0^+}^{+∞}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}dx$ convergent or divergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3137138) It seems to be a series of questions in the same excercise.

Comment: The integral is convergent and is: $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1} \,dx  =\frac{\pi ^2}{3}$

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $x=u^2$ to get 
$$I=2\int_0^{\infty} \frac {u}{e^u -1}du$$

Using that $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac {u^{s-1}}{e^u -1}du =\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)$$ For $\Re (s) \gt 1$

We have $$I=2\Gamma(2)\zeta(2)=\frac {\pi^2}{3}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help . Though I don't know how to do advance procedures to do an integration .Is there any easier way to do that ? Thanks a lot anyway